# Sentient manta rays living in Jupiter?

Tags: identification-request

I am trying to remember a science fiction story I read that involved a civilization of sentient manta rays living in Jupiter. The book starts with the main character, a human, being given a body to join the manta rays, and ends with the humans and manta rays realizing that they can use the core of Jupiter to travel to other solar systems. I would have read this in the late 90s, earlier 2000s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably **Timothy Zahn's *Manta's Gift***.

From the [Goodreads summary](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/216441.Manta_s_Gift):

> When Matt Raimey had his accident, he thought his life was over. He never dreamed, in his wildest fantasies, that he'd end up in a spot like this. In the toxic atmosphere of Jupiter, born into the body of an enormous creature that looked like a cross between a manta ray and a dolphin, he is living a new life, unlike any humankind had previously experienced.

Also at [the Science Fiction Review](https://www.scifi-review.net/mantas-gift-by-timothy-zahn.html) with more details about the story (although without revealing the ending).

When I searched Google for `science fiction manta rays jupiter`, the top hits were all about this book. Then again, Google search results are different for everyone, and I've done a lot of searching for science fiction stories to answer people's story-ID questions; maybe you'd get completely different results with the same search.

Answer (score 1):

Iain M Banks, The Algebraist. It involves nearly immortal manta ray like creatures living in a gas giant, with a gate in its core.

Comment: I thought about this but there are too many details that don't match -- (i) in *The Algebraist*, the protagonist (Fassin Taak) is not "given a body" but uses a miniature spaceship; (ii) the Dwellers only resemble manta rays as infants; they change shape as they grow and as adults they resemble dumb-bells; (iii) *The Algebraist* does not take place on Jupiter (which is said to be uninhabited) but on the planet Nasqueron.